# how to merge two calculation function together in javascript

Tags: javascript

first of all, i have 2 type of calculation function 
the first one handle the check box and the second one handle the radio 
I want the total calculation display in a text box.
the following sample works but it will overide each other when i checked neither of it.

```
//calculate price
var checks = document.getElementsByName('e');
for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++)
    checks[i].onclick = function () {
        var cal = document.getElementsByName('e');
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < cal.length; i++) {
            if (cal[i].checked)
                total += parseFloat(cal[i].getAttribute('data'));
        }
        document.getElementsByName('total')[0].value = '$' + total;
    }

//calculate radio price
var tick = document.getElementsByName('d');
tick.forEach(function (value) {
    if (value.checked)
        document.getElementsByName('total')[0].value = '$' + value.getAttribute('data');
})
for (var i = 0; i < tick.length; i++)
    tick[i].onclick = function () {
        var rad = document.getElementsByName('d');
        var sc = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
            if (rad[i].checked)
                sc += parseFloat(rad[i].getAttribute('data'));
        }
        document.getElementsByName('total')[0].value = '$' + sc;
    }
```

but when i tried to get the total sum of both value by remove the

> document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + total ;
>   and  document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + sc ;

and merge both of it together by

> document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + total +sc ;

it gave me an error " total or sc is underfine". 
is there any suggestion or tips for me to get the sum of the both calculation?

Comment: You can simplify your code Alot by putting the events on the parent element of the checkboxes and the radios. Then you only have to add the event once instead of to each element. Also by using `addEventListener('click')` instead of element.onclick = function(){}` you can bind multiple functions to the same element instead of overwriting the event.

Comment: can u provide me some example ? i 'm new to javascript and i still cnt solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using some functions that you might not have encountered yet, but I've tried to add enough comments to explain what's happening.

```js
// Grab the divs that contains the checkboxes and radios
// document.querySelector can replace getElementById/Name/ClassName using the same syntax as css selectors.
var checkboxWrapper = document.querySelector('#prices-checkboxes');
var radioWrapper = document.querySelector('#prices-radios');
// Let's make one counting function that handles both the cechkboxes and the radios.
// Since it will be an event handler, it will have an 'event' object as its first parameter.
var calculatePrice = function( event ) {
 // We want to sum all the checkboxes, so we can just select them all out of the wrapper.
 // But we get an html collection, where we want an array, so we can cast it to an array as well at the same time.
 var checkedBoxes = Array.prototype.slice.call( checkboxWrapper.querySelectorAll('input:checked') );
 // The total of the checkboxes is just a reduction from many checkboxes to one number. This is similar to a for loop.
 var boxPrice = checkedBoxes.reduce(function( total, box ) {
  // Notice how we don't use floating point numbers here.
  // It's VERY important to not do calculations with floats when you work with money
  // Rounding errors can make the total be off, which leads to unhappy customers.
  // So we do all maths with integers and just divide the total by 100 in the end.
  var price = parseInt(box.getAttribute('data-price'), 10);
  total += price;
  return total;
 }, 0);
 // We also want the radio button that is checked, if any. Since radio buttons with the same name belong to the same group, this will always be only ONE radio.
 // So we can use querySelector instead of querySelectorAll so we only get One element instead of a collection we need to cast to an array.
 var checkedRadio = radioWrapper.querySelector('input:checked');
 // If there is no radio selected, the radio price is automatically 0
 // We can use a ternary here. This is just shorthand for: "if (checkedRadio) radioPrice = parseInt(checkedRadio.getAttribute('data-price'), 10); else radioPrice = 0;"
 var radioPrice = (checkedRadio) ? parseInt(checkedRadio.getAttribute('data-price'), 10) : 0;
 // Calculate the total price string, divide it by 100 so we have dollars again instead of cents and add/remove any trailing zeroes.
 // Always do the maths first, then determine how the result should be visualized.
 var realPriceString = '$' + ((boxPrice + radioPrice) / 100).toFixed(2);
 // Render the total price.
 document.querySelector('#total').innerHTML = realPriceString
 
 
 
}
// We want to add the event handler to the wrappers themselves. This way we only have to add it once, instead of for each checkbox and radio.
// addEventListener gives you more control than onclick, since onclick handlers will overwrite eachother.
checkboxWrapper.addEventListener('click', calculatePrice);
radioWrapper.addEventListener('click', calculatePrice);
```

```html
 <div id="prices-checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" data-price="1514">$15.14</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-price="2556">$25.56</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-price="3574">$35.74</input>
  <input type="checkbox" data-price="4556">$45.56</input>
 </div>
 <div id="prices-radios">
  <input type="radio" name="radio-price" data-price="0">$0.00</input>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-price" data-price="1478">$14.78</input>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-price" data-price="7481">$74.81</input>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-price" data-price="2545">$25.45</input>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-price" data-price="7812">$78.12</input>
 </div>
 <div id="total">$0.00</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to declare total and sc outside the forloops.
You can declare them on the top 
May be after this step

```js
var checks = document.getElementsByName('e');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a common Variable as Final total and assign to that

```
var Finaltotal =0;

  var checks = document.getElementsByName('e');
    for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) 
        checks[i].onclick = function() {
    var cal = document.getElementsByName('e');
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cal.length; i++) {
        if (cal[i].checked) 
        total += parseFloat(cal[i].getAttribute("data"));

  }
Finaltotal = total;
    document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + total ;

}

 //calculate radio price
    var tick = document.getElementsByName('d');
    tick.forEach(function(value){
        if (value.checked)
            document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value ="$" + value.getAttribute('data');

})
for (var i = 0; i < tick.length; i++) 
    tick[i].onclick = function() {
  var rad = document.getElementsByName('d');
  var sc = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    if (rad[i].checked) 
      sc += parseFloat(rad[i].getAttribute("data"));

  }
  document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + sc ;
Finaltotal = Finaltotal + sc ;
}
```

Hope this will help you